# Question about determinants and orthogonal complement. Prove that this vector belongs to $S^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, orthogonality

This is one of my linear algebra questions:

Let $S=\{\textbf{v}_1,\textbf{v}_2,\cdots,\textbf{v}_{n-1}\}$ be a set of $n-1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Define an $n\times n$ matrix A such that the first column of A is $(\textbf{e}_1,\textbf{e}_2,\cdots,\textbf{e}_n)^T$, and the ith column of A is $\textbf{v}_{i-1}$ for $i=2,3,...,n$. We regard $\textbf{e}_1,\textbf{e}_2,\cdots,\textbf{e}_n$ as some variables and compute detA. The result obtained is a linear combination of $\textbf{e}_1,\textbf{e}_2,\cdots,\textbf{e}_n$, which can be interpreted as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that this vector belongs to $S^\perp$.

I considered the case when n=3. Then it can be interpreted as the cross-product of $\textbf{v}_1,\textbf{v}_2$.
I also know that $S^\perp$ contains a nonzero vector.
However, since I don't have explicit numbers for $\textbf{v}_1,\textbf{v}_2,\cdots,\textbf{v}_n$, I don't know how to proceed from here.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

[Edit]:

The notation here seemed confusing to me as well when I first saw this question. Actually, an explicit example is given.

(For example, if $n=3,\textbf{v}_1=(0,1,2)^T,\textbf{v}_2=(3,0,4)^T$, then we have $detA=\begin{vmatrix}\textbf{e}_1&0&3\\\textbf{e}_2&1&0\\\textbf{e}_3&2&4\end{vmatrix}=4\textbf{e}_1+6\textbf{e}_2-\textbf{e}_3=(4,6,-3)^T$)

Comment: You should use different variables names for $(\textbf{e}_1,\textbf{e}_2,\cdots,\textbf{e}_n)^T$ and the linear combination. It is currently confusing.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  I've edited this question since an explicit example was provided, so perhaps the variable names shouldn't change.

Comment: Again, the question is poorly written. I suspect that $\textbf{e}_1,\textbf{e}_2,\cdots,\textbf{e}_n$ is supposed to be the canonical basis here. Is it the case?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net For illustration, when $n=3$ this is the (commonly taught and used) [formal determinant formula of the cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation). In $n$ dimensions, this generalizes the 3D cross product to a "co-unary" cross product (a combination of the Hodge star operator and a musical isomorphism, to drop more fancy names).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*.

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n
\end{pmatrix} \cdot\,
\det\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{e}_1 & v_{11}~~ & \cdots & v_{1(n-1)}~~ \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\mathbf{e}_n & v_{(n-1)1} & \cdots & v_{(n-1)(n-1)}
\end{pmatrix} =
\det \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & v_{11}~~ & \cdots & v_{1(n-1)}~~ \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_n & v_{(n-1)1} & \cdots & v_{(n-1)(n-1)}
\end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: What are $\{\mathrm{e}_1, \dots,\mathrm{e}_n\}$ in above formula?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I expect you know it's the coordinate basis.

Comment: That would be natural for me. But as the question mentions *$\mathrm{e}_1, \dots,\mathrm{e}_n$ as some variables*, it would be valuable to clarify that point!

Comment: @elemelons Thanks a lot; I guess this is the key!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net OP means compute the determinant by treating the first column's entries first as formal variables, then evaluate the formal variables at the coordinate basis. (Like I said, compare with the usual formal determinant formula for the cross product. I don't know if OP has the background the describe this abstraction.)

Comment: @Lumos BTW you can see the equality in my answer by writing the cofactor expansion along the first column. When $n=3$ this is none other than the triple product identity ${\bf a}\cdot({\bf v}_1\times{\bf v}_2)=\det({\bf a}~{\bf v}_1~{\bf v}_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this answer is based on some interpretation of the question which is rather unclear.* The main interpretation is that $\{\mathrm{e}_1, \dots,\mathrm{e}_n\}$ stands for the canonical basis in the question.

So let $V = \mathbb R^n$. The map

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\varphi : & V & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & x & \longmapsto &  \det(x, v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}) \end{array}
$$ is a linear form. We have $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}\} \subseteq \{\varphi\}^\perp$ as $\varphi(x)=0$ for $x \in \operatorname{Span}\{v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}\}$. Taking the annihilator of both sides of the above inclusion, we get

$$\mathbb R \varphi = \{\varphi\}^{\perp \perp} \subseteq \operatorname{Span}\{v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}\}^{\perp}$$ which is exactly meaning that the vector $\det((\mathrm{e}_1, \dots,\mathrm{e}_n)^T, v_1, \dots, v_{n-1})$ belongs to $S^\perp$ **with the interpretation of the question that $\{\mathrm{e}_1, \dots,\mathrm{e}_n\}$ stands for the canonical basis.**